# How to return to new array from Array of elements?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an array of elements I want to map to a new array of objects with a key as a name.

```
let array = ["abc", "def", "xyx"]
```

Expected Output

```
let array1 = [{name: "abc"}, {name: "def"}, {name: "xyz"}]
```

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array.map`:

```
let newArray = array1.map((value) => ({name: value});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let newArr = arr.map(el => ({ name: el }));

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: I was lazy writing out the string values, but it actually results in an array of objects, just as the expected output is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

you can use map() function for that,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```js
    let array = ["abc", "def", "xyx"]
    const array1 = array.map( data => { 
    return {name:data}
    })
    /* this code will also work,if you dint specify the properties name 
    by default it will be the variable's name. In this case 'name' */
     const array2 = array.map( name => { 
    return {name}
    })
    console.log(array1)
    console.log(array2)
```